# Why does Google crawl  my site very slowly [recently]

Tags: seo

recently it takes 5 to 8 days for my site  ([www.StudyHorror.com](http://www.StudyHorror.com)) to be indexed. I'm updating the website everyday.

What are the possible causes for this problem?

Comment: For Example, this url [link](http://www.studyhorror.com/writings/IELTS-Writing-Task-2-Should-Parents-Be-Obliged-To-Immunise-Their-Children/10) hasn't been indexed on Google for 6 days. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Here is your reason

http://www.studyhorror.com/robots.txt

**User-agent: * Disallow:**

Remove that !

Comment: That should definately do it.

Comment: ??? OMG! why? I thought every site must have one robots.txt. Can you please explain for me?

Comment: @studyhorror this  http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html and this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard should help you

Comment: @HackToHell, Chris J. Lee: Thanks you guys for your help! All the best to you! Kind Regards!

Comment: The robots.txt appears to be blank now but having `Disallow:` with nothing after it doesn't block anything, so this definitely isn't the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add into your comment the option to adjust google crawl rate.

I think it's just a suggestion to Goolge how frequently we are confident for Google to update the content. If it's too high, it can consume heaps of our bandwidth.

Therefore, it's not possible to adjust Google crawl rate by setting that up. :)

Answer (score 0):

If your site crawl slowly and you want fast crawling then you have to update your site's crawl rate in google webmaster tool.

here it is:

**To change the crawl rate:**

1. On the Webmaster Tools Home page, click the site you want.
2. Under Site configuration, click Settings.
3. In the Crawl rate section, select the option you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'd follow the recommendations people gave and if you want even faster Index make sure you have a sitemap and update it frequently or when adding fresh content.